# Photo overflowed by infinite pixels

Tags: flutter

I am trying to attach a photo to the top of the screen, and extend it to the left and ride edges, but only go down 0.2.

This is the code I am using to do so

```
final logo =  Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            "assets/SignUp_Photo.jpg",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

However, using this code causes me to overflow the bottom by infinity pixels.

How can I rectify?

Calling logo as follows:

```
 return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
          body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(36),
              child: Container(
                height: mq.size.height,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    logo,
                    text,
                    fields,
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
                      child: bottom,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

mq size height is

```
final mq = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

Comment: You need to have the column widget directly inside singlechildscrollview

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image within a `Container`.  And assign height and with to the Container

```
final logo =  
        Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Image.asset(
                   "assets/SignUp_Photo.jpg",
           fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
        );
```

Calling logo as follows:

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
  body: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Container(
        height: mq.size.height,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            logo,
            text,
            fields,
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
              child: bottom,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: In which dimension it overflows?

Comment: At the bottom of it

Comment: Only want it to be 0.2 height but stick to the top

Comment: As you are using single widget inside Column, you need not using Column. If it is needed wrap with a `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Can you please provide answer

Comment: Use `mainAxosAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start` in the column for sticking on the top

Comment: That still does not solve the problem with overflowing by infinity pixels though...

Comment: The provided answer is working fine for me. It may occur overflows on where you calling  logo

Comment: Just added where I am calling logo. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Also added where I am calling Mq

Answer (score 0):

You need to put Column directly under Singlechildscrollview and wrap your logo inside the container:

```dart
return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
          body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(36),
              child:  Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                   Container(
                height: mq.size.height,
                child: logo),
                    text,
                    fields,
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 150),
                      child: bottom,
                    ),
                  ],
                
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```